# Docker compose up before build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, build

Here is a simpler version of the docker compose file that I am using:

```
version:"3.9"

services:
  db:
    ...

  webapp:
    build:
      context: ./config
    depends on:
      - "db"
    ...
```

Whenever I run the command `docker-compose up -d`, here is the order of what Docker executes:

1. Build the container for the web app
2. If successful, it boots all containers based on the order of what the `depends on` requirement

I was wondering if that was possible to boot first the db service on its own, then build the web app, and finally boot everything? I need it since the build of the web app requires the database to be up and running for some build steps. I would like to keep everything in one docker-compose.yml file and with as few commands if possible.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I do not think you can - in a compose - make the build happen after startup of other containers, however I suspect that is because it is not really the right way to do things with containers. Generally a build should not need other containers - sure it might need registries, etc. and they could be containers, but a build should not 'perform operations' on other containers. I suspect that your building container is going to deploy a data model or data into the ``db`` container? I think that should really be a startup script or something in the 'build' container.

Comment: It's not possible.  If nothing else, at a mechanical layer, (a) Compose doesn't have any way to order build dependencies and (b) the `docker build` environment won't be on the Docker networks Compose sets up.  Also consider what might happen if you build an image, then reset the database, then re-run the same image against another database.  I say a little more in the linked question.